# MySQL STR_TO_DATE returns NULL on correct FORMAT

Tags: mysql, function, datetime

Something weird is happening with all my MySQL installations. STR_TO_DATE returns null no matter what I put in the function. Whether I put in an example from the MySQL documentation page or my own query, it returns `NULL`.

EXAMPLES:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("5", '%k' );
-- EXAMPLE FROM MySQL Doc Page --
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%m');
```

Both return `NULL`

Is there any setting I need to change or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date:

> If the [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) or [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date) mode is enabled, zero dates or part of dates are disallowed. In that case, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and generates a warning

Since you are trying to create “dates” from only an hour/only a month, respectively, the other date parts are effectively zero, and therefor the result depends on the settings the manual mentions.

Comment: do I have to disable it for every session or can I make it global?